# Find multiple files in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I constantly work with large projects containing 100s of files and would like the ability to filter by multiple files so my solution explorer only shows those files.

For example:
web.config,File1.cs,File1.js,Global.asax...

This way I can easily navigate back and forth in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my [Favorite Documents](https://vlasovstudio.com/favorite-documents/) extension. It allows you to quickly open chosen files or jump to them in Solution Explorer.

Comment: I will try this this as soon as I get a chance. I think this will be my answer thank you!

Comment: This is actually a pretty good solution.  however, it would be nice if it could also filter the view on the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to alter the solution itself?

If so, right click the solution, **Add New Solution Folder**, name it something you'll recognize, then do **Add Existing Item** operation(s) to put in the files you'd like to see.

There is no requirement for a file to be in only one folder.

Do this multiple times and collapse the solution folders you're not working with at the time.  You can even create a multi-level hierarchy if you want to organize a lot of them.

Is the problem somehow more complex than this, and I'm missing a point?

-Noel

Comment: This sounds like an interesting solution let me give this a try.